# WordPress SQL Statement? - DELETE all users WHERE User Role is Subscriber AND have posted NO comments?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a database with 30K mostly spam user registrations. The site was previously active with users, but has grown quiet. I'd like to clean up the database to remove all of the subscribers in the databse who have not posted any comments. I will leave all other roles (Author, Contributor...) in place.

I've used the following to remove all subscribers in the past...

```
DELETE 
    wp_users, 
    wp_usermeta 
FROM 
    wp_users 
    INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id 
WHERE 
    meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' AND 
    meta_value LIKE '%subscriber%'
```

*Can the above be adjusted to remove only subscribers with NO comments?*

I've also tried this...

```
DELETE FROM `wp_users`
WHERE ID NOT IN
(SELECT DISTINCT post_author FROM `wp_posts`);
```

That deleted ALL of the subscribers, AND left all of their comments in place. So that's not right. (It looks to have deleted all users who had no posts.)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this code,

```
<?php
add_action('init', 'removeusers');
function removeusers(){
$args = array(
    'role'    => 'subscriber',
    'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
    'order'   => 'ASC'
);

$users = get_users( $args ); 
   foreach ( $users as $user ) {

   $args = array('user_id' => $user->ID);
   $usercomment = get_comments($args);

   if(count($usercomment) < 1){
       require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/user.php' );
       $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
      wp_delete_user( $user->ID );
   } 
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: I tried running that as a PHP file in the root of the site, and it did not work.

Comment: Where you have added it?

Comment: I edited this, not put the code in your functions.php file

Comment: I did not put the code into functions.php. I created a PHP file and just named it run.php. I added the code you provided, and the edited code you provided. Error: This page isn’t working. [website] is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: you should put this code in functions.php file

Comment: Unfortunately, the server does not seem to be able to handle the load. Crashed everything within a second. I have added the code into functions.php, but got the same error. There are 30,000 + users.
I did ask about a SQL query to run, and I would prefer to go that route. Thank you.

Comment: I THINK this worked, even though the server provided an Error 500 when implemented, and it also crashed the website. I was able to FTP in and remove the code from functions.php and get the site back up without having to restore from backup.

Comment: This SQL Query also worked without causing an issue with the site.

`DELETE FROM wp_users 
        WHERE ID IN (
            SELECT user_id 
            FROM wp_usermeta 
            WHERE meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' 
            AND meta_value = 'a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";b:1;}'
        ) 
        AND ID NOT IN (
            SELECT user_id 
            FROM wp_comments
        )`

Then orphan clean up...

`DELETE FROM wp_usermeta
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM wp_users
 WHERE wp_usermeta.user_id = wp_users.ID
)`